# Dual boot windows 8.1 stuck

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 in my system. I have used boot repair tool  in Ubuntu to fix the grub. Now the boot menu is showing( Before it was not showing). I am also able to boot to Ubuntu. But after selecting Windows from boot menu and press enter. All i am getting a weired screen. Windows is not loading. This is the paste screen boot repair generated http://paste.ubuntu.com/10568910/. Somebody Please help me to fix this.

---

Thanks for the response. I am able to manually select windows from the drop down. Then after that it is not starting up windows. All i am getting is Ubuntu's purple color background and many strikes all over it. I have almost figured out what is the issue here. 
In http://paste.ubuntu.com/10568910/ it says.

> The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
>   Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
>   read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
>   mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot-sav/sda1

The issue seems to be Windows's fast start up. It needs to be disabled. Now i have to disable it. But the issue is i have to boot to Windows to disable it, and that is what currently i am not able to do.

---

Fixed issue now. All i did was, boot into windows using live cd. Then run

`bootrec/fixmbr`

bootrec/fixboot

Then i am able to boot into my windows. Turned off fast startup from Power options. After that used Ubuntu loaded pen drive to boot to Ubuntu and fix the grub.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed issue now. All i did was, boot into windows using live cd. Then run

`bootrec/fixmbr`

bootrec/fixboot

Then i am able to boot into my windows. Turned off fast startup from Power options. After that used Ubuntu loaded pen drive to boot to Ubuntu and fix the grub.

Answer (score 0):

Can you still get to windows if you manually select your Windows partition before you get to the Ubuntu boot options screen (pressing either F10 or F12 while the computer is first starting up and then selecting Windows in this boot menu)? I can't say I know how to fix your loader, but if the above works and Windows boots then at least you can rule out your Windows installation being damaged. I've also experienced strange things happen when Windows was in the middle of applying updates and I hadn't yet booted back into Windows to let it finish.