# dual boot: windows 8.1 boot failur,stuck with grub screen

Tags: dual-boot, windows

Dual boot are working fine till yesterday... until today, when i start my computer and start windows 8.1 from grub menu, windows 8.1 stuck with grub screen, no further progress.

after boot repair, again it works fine, but in next boot it shows same problem...

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10820273/

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have a common problem, except my computer just refuses to boot into Ubuntu.

Disable Windows fast startup, then boot into windows using the live cd. Run the command `bootrec/fixmbr` and you should  be good to go.

This may be what you're looking for if you would like to know more:

[Dual boot windows 8.1 stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594688/dual-boot-windows-8-1-stuck?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your problem is just the crappy hibernation win 8 does. BTW this feature has many more disadvantages. So you should disable it. To avoid such problems, I would suggest that you install both OS in uefi mode as far as you not already have done. Then you will have no MBR anymore and so you will avoid a lot of dual boot problems.

Comment: how can i dissable this feature?? im newbee,give me some instruction how to dissable it..    Thanks for help...

Comment: I think this is a good description: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-or-enable-fast-startup-in-windows-8-1/

Comment: i have already did this.   but error persist..

Comment: Is it win 8.1 or 8.1 pro?

Comment: Ok I read the output a second time and mentioned some strange things with your Installation. Did you move some partitions with a tool? It also could be that windows does not detect that an existing image is corrupted and so it tries to load instead of deleting.

Comment: windows 8.1 pro

Comment: i have used AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition 5.6 to make some partition. After few days i have completely formated my HDD with Gparted. Then i installed Win 8.1, then ubuntu in different partition.Dual boot was nice at begining, After an week of installation i found this problem.